# Handler doesn’t receive batteryState notifications

Tags: ios, swift

My batteryStateDidChange handler never gets called (on either Simulator or iPhone). I’ve found several examples (usually old) on this site and I’ve been through the Apple documentation. I also get the pid error: “cannot attach to process due to System Integrity Protection” when I build but not sure if this would be the cause. Although I’ve been programming since the 1970’s, I’ve never used Swift or Xcode before. I’m using Swift 4 and Xcode 9.1. Help would be appreciated.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        //Tell UIDevice that we want battery notifications
            UIDevice.current.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true

        // Register to listen for notifications
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(batteryStateDidChange(_notification:)), name: Notification.Name.UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChange, object: nil)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    var batteryState: UIDeviceBatteryState {
        return UIDevice.current.batteryState
    }

    // Handle the batteryStateDidChange notification  <---- This never gets called
    @objc func batteryStateDidChange(_notification: Notification) {
        switch batteryState {
        case .unplugged, .unknown:
            print("not charging")
        case .charging, .full:
            print("charging or full")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be a space character after the underscore

```
@objc func batteryStateDidChange(_ notification: Notification)
```

and the selector is simply

```
#selector(batteryStateDidChange)
```

Comment: **Excellent!** Thank you for correcting my code (those pesky spaces!). After pulling out my hair for a week, the code now works with your corrections. As a veteran programmer, I have little hair left anyway... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Code is looking fine. batteryStateDidChange will be called only when the battery state changes(unplugged to charging or charging to Full).

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(batteryStateDidChange(_notification:)), name: .UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChange, object: nil)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The code works without adding (_notification:) to the batteryStateDidChange selector - see the answer from vadian.